# Remove swipe animation in DeckSwiper NativeBase

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I am using [DeckSwiper](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#deckswiper-def-headref) from [NativeBase](https://nativebase.io/). This is how it looks when i run it in device.

[image]

Now i want to remove swipe animation from it, does there any property for this?

Comment: You said "i want to remove swipe animation from it."  what do you mean by that?  How do you want it now?